# How do I import a Cython function with array arguments to Numba?

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numba

The Numba documentation describes [how to import a Cython function](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/extending/high-level.html#importing-cython-functions) by creating a `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE`. However, the Cython function in the example only takes a scalar argument. I have a Cython function that takes arrays. How do I initialize the corresponding `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE` object?

Cython function:

```
cimport numpy as np


ctypedef np.float64_t FLOAT64


cdef api void generate_options(
        FLOAT64 [:] y_error,
        ...
    ):
    ...
```

The Numba documentation describes [how to create array types](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/types.html#arrays). However, using these in `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE` raises `TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ has no from_param method`, so I assume they are not intended to be used as `argtypes`.

---

## Edit:

The solution suggested in the comments calls the function from Numba, but produces a segmentation error when I try to take a slice. If I comment out the last line before `return` then there is no error. Am I doing something wrong with the c types?

Cython:

```
ctypedef np.int8_t INT8
ctypedef np.int64_t INT64
ctypedef np.float64_t FLOAT64


cdef api void generate_options(
        FLOAT64 [:] y_error,
        FLOAT64 [:,:] x,
        FLOAT64 [:] x_pads,
        INT8 [:] x_active,
        INT64 [:,:] indexes,
        long i_start,
        INT64 [:] i_start_by_x,
        INT64 [:] i_stop_by_x,
        int error,
        double delta,
        # buffers
        FLOAT64 [:,:] new_error,
        INT8 [:,:] new_sign,
    ):
    cdef:
        size_t n_stims = new_error.shape[0]
        size_t i_stim
        FLOAT64 [:] x_stim

    for i_stim in range(n_stims):
        if x_active[i_stim] == 0:
            continue
        x_stim = x[i_stim]
    return
```

Python:

```
addr = ...
functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(
    None,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int8),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64),
    ctypes.c_int64,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64),
    ctypes.c_int,
    ctypes.c_double,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int8),
)
opt_generate_options = functype(addr)
```

Comment: Can you figure out the correct calling syntax from C? It looks like that something more than just (double * y_error) is required (striding information may be required too, since this array could be non c-contiguous).

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're asking for, but Cython uses this for array parameters:
```
typedef struct {
  struct __pyx_memoryview_obj *memview;
  char *data;
  Py_ssize_t shape[8];
  Py_ssize_t strides[8];
  Py_ssize_t suboffsets[8];
} __Pyx_memviewslice;
```

Comment: For simple dtypes (double*, size_t) you can do this like that: https://numba.discourse.group/t/extending-lapack-functions-into-numba/1394/4 Maybe this is an option?

Comment: Thanks! This allows calling the function, but results in a segmentation error. I added the code to the question above. Do you see anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: A cython array slice isn't the same as a pointer, so the way you've done it definitely won't work. I think the suggestion was to rewrite the function to take pointers and ints rather than memoryview slices

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood – do you have a pointer on how to rewrite the Cython function? I am trying with argument `double* y_error` and then converting to array with `cdef view.array y_error_ = <double[:n_times]> y_error` but that causes a segfault, so can't be right. (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays)

Comment: @christianbrodbeck - I am running into a similar problem. Did you ever find a solution or workaround for this? Cheers

Comment: No, I ended up rewriting everything in Cython, sorry.